# How to know if TCL script executed successfully in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have written a TCL script where at the and of the file I wrote:

```
exit 1
```

but in the places when the script encounters to a bad situation it calls:

```
exit 0
```

Now, in a bash script I should call the TCL script and know if the execution of the TCL script completed successfully or no, and depending on that I should do one or another thing. So I wrote the following in BASH:
    if tclsh myScript.tcl"arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
    then
       #do something
    else
       #do some another thing
    fi

But it does not do what it should. What's the problem here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tclsh myScript.tcl "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Script failed"
else
    echo "Script OK"
fi
```

Answer (score 2):

Normally zero means success, and nonzero - false. I would advise against changing it, because it can be misleading.
In your case i believe it does exactly the opposite, so either you stick to the habitual way of using statuses, or negate every check.

As for your code, try like this:

```
if tclsh myScript.tcl "arg1" "arg2" "arg3"; then 
  # tcl script returns error
else 
  # tcl script returns ok
fi
```

Don't forget the semicolons.